# How to make if cond on exact count?

Tags: php

I use PHP and ODBC, and I was wondering how to make if condition for an exact number...?

```
$DB = $core_db->Execute("SELECT TOP (10) ID, Name, Age, Location FROM Profiles ORDER BY Name");
$num=0; 

while(!$DB->EOF){
    if ($DB->fields[0] != 0) {  
        echo'<div class="ID">'.++$num.'</div>
             <div class="name">'.$DB->fields[1].'</div>
             <div class="name">'.$DB->fields[2].'</div>
             <div class="name">'.$DB->fields[3].'</div>
            ';
    }
$DB->MoveNext();
```

Now I want to use if with `echo'<div class="ID">'.++$num.'</div>` to stylize first 3 profile but I don't know how!

I tried

```
if ($num === 1){
    echo'<div class="ID">1*</div>';
} else {
    echo'<div class="ID">'.++$num.'</div>';
}
```

and it didn't work with me, it gave 1* to all rows not first one only.

Comment: Not sure what you dont know how to do, as you seem to have done it?

Comment: A side comment: there's no any sense to use PHP for static HTML rendering. You can always disable PHP interpreter for it and enable when it necessary.

Comment: if ($num === 1){ << this didn't work with me, it gave 1* to all rows not first one only.

Comment: Obviously, you can't reach the second if/else block because you don't increment the `$num` value in the first block.

Comment: so how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$DB = $core_db->Execute("SELECT TOP (10) ID, Name, Age, Location FROM Profiles 
ORDER BY Name");
$num=0; 

while(!$DB->EOF){
 if ($DB->fields[0] != 0) {  
     echo'<div class="ID">'.$num.'</div>
         <div class="name">'.$DB->fields[1].'</div>
         <div class="name">'.$DB->fields[2].'</div>
         <div class="name">'.$DB->fields[3].'</div>
        ';
     $num++;
    }
$DB->MoveNext();
```

try this, here I'm incrementing your $num when it runs from each loop.
here I'm doing  post-increment,

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple

```
if ($num == 1){
echo'<div class="ID">1*</div>';
$num = $num + 1;
} else {
echo'<div class="ID">'.$num.'</div>';
$num = $num + 1;
}
```